# Windows 8 App error: "class not registered" (visual basic) with Visual Studio when simply trying to open Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, com, windows-8

I am fairly new to programming with Visual Studio/Visual Basic.

I am trying to write a Windows 8 Metro App with Visual Studio 2012 for Windows 8. I use Outlook 2007. It is supposed to open up an Outlook application but crashes with following error (hopefully without translation errors):

**Additional Information: An instance of the COM-Component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} couldn't be created because of the following error of CoCreateInstanceFromApp : 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). Make sure that your COM-Object is in the list of CoCreateInstanceFromApp.**

This is all the code I put in except for the standard code provided by visual studio:

> Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop 'at the very start
>   Dim oOutlook As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application  'in Sub

I tried also:

> Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application

as seen elsewhere.

I tried to find info online but they only relate to servers and un-approved COMs. Microsoft should approve of Outlook though.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this so it opens up a window of Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you are trying to accomplish is not allowed.  You cannot invoke code written specifically for the desktop inside of a modern UI. This includes Microsoft products, even Outlook.  If you have the need for code to be shared, you can use the [Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) when writing new code, but this will not help you invoke legacy code via COM or other mechanism.